# Java threads organization guidance

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, swing

I have created an application which queries a MySQL database for a list of items. The resulting data set is parsed into individual Objects and they are passed throughout the program in `ArrayLists`.

Currently, during the initial database connection, and any subsequent queries, the GUI of my program will hang. To counter this, i would like to transition my DatabaseManager class to run in a separate thread.

<strike>I am curious how I should handle passing the data between the GUI and the DatabaseManager thread.</strike>

Actually, I am more curious how i would create a single class to handle all of the database functionality that I have already implemented, but run it all in a separate thread.

The current method definitions include, but are not limited to

- initConnection()
- query(String SQLQuery)
- printResultSet()

Ideally, these functions would be called from the GUI and would return very quickly. How would i go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was in the same situation, I used an [Akka typed actor](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.2/java/typed-actors.html) for the DatabaseManager (it's a thread underneath). I sent asynchronous requests from my table model to my "Database actor", and then updated the GUI/AbstractTableModel with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from the Actor. It worked well, but you can also do it with threads manually.

Comment: This is very helpful, but i guess i asked the wrong question. See above edit.